# Есть ли библиотека на javascript, которая конвертирует файл sql database (.RDB) в формат .CSV?

Tags: javascript, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли библиотека на javascript, которая конвертирует файл sql database (.RDB) в формат .CSV? Или может пример?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плагин для чтения sql database - https://github.com/kripken/sql.js